# TCPDF doesn't load http image link if server is https (SSL active)

Tags: php

I've an tinymce editor on my PHP webapp to save "precompiled" content (text/images).

I've saved an old entry with some text and a image link. This is the HTML view of tinymce editor.

```
<p>This is an image</p>
<img src="http://mywebapp.com/files/image_1.jpg" />
```

Then a button named "Create PDF and SEND"...create the A4 pdf version of my tinymce content (using TCPDF) and send via email.

All ok when my app was on http. Now we migrated to http**s** and when i generate PDF, image disappear from PDF....i need to manually change (in html view of tinymce editor textarea):

```
<img src="http://mywebapp.com/files/image_1.jpg" />
```

to:

```
<img src="https://mywebapp.com/files/image_1.jpg" />
```

adding **s** to src. Is there a way to replace all http: to https: referred only to mywebapp.com domain?
Or better, there is a solution to fix this problem on TCPDF?